# Questions about the process of finding a special solution for 1-dimension Heat equation (diffusion equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

I recently learn the method to solve the 1-dimension Heat equation (diffusion equation),namely
\begin{cases}
u_t=ku_{xx},  & \text{$-\infty \lt x \lt \infty,0\lt t \lt \infty$} \\
u(x,o)=\phi(x)
\end{cases}
The professor's goal is to look for is the one,denoted as $Q(x,0)$ ,which satisfies the initial condition

$Q(x,0) = 1$, $\text{for $x \gt 0 $}$ ,$Q(x,0) = 0$, $\text{for $x \lt 0 $}$

First , the professor then says he is looking for $Q(x,0)$ of the special form
$Q(x,0)=g(p)$,where $p=\frac{x}{\sqrt{4kt}}$

The professor prove this claim initially by setting $Q(x,t)=g(m\frac{x}{t^\alpha})$

He then have $Q_t=g'(m\frac{x}{t^\alpha})(-\frac{\alpha}{t}m\frac{x}{t^\alpha})$ and $kQ_{xx}=kg''(m\frac{x}{t^\alpha})(\frac{x^2}{t^{2\alpha}})$
Hence $Q_t -kQ_{xx} $= $\frac{1}{t}(m^2\alpha \frac{x}{t^\alpha}g'(m\frac{x}{t^\alpha})+kg''(\frac{m^2}{t^{2\alpha-1}}g''(m\frac{x}{t^\alpha}))$

Therefore,$t^{2\alpha-1}$=the constant so that the term $m^2\alpha \frac{x}{t^\alpha}g'(m\frac{x}{t^\alpha})+kg''(\frac{m^2}{t^{2\alpha-1}}g''(m\frac{x}{t^\alpha}))$ only depends on $Q$

If $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$,then choose $m=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4k}}$.Hence $Q(x,0)=g(p)$,where $p=\frac{x}{\sqrt{4kt}}$

What i dont know is that why we initally set $Q(x,t)=g(m\frac{x}{t^\alpha})$,in particular, how do we initially know that we need to set $m\frac{x}{t^\alpha}$ inside $g$?

Comment: This was very difficult to read, so you may want to clean up some of your writing. Anyway, $g$ is what is known as a [self-similar solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-similar_solution), and it comes from searching for a solution to the problem that is [scale-invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_invariance). The notes [here](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahhwi/LTCC/sectionB-similarity.pdf) provide a detailed exposition on computing a self-similar solution for the heat equation and should hopefully clear up where the guess $Q = g(mxt^{-\alpha})$ comes from.